# Conditional Count in Python

Tags: python

If I have the following:

```
team = [
    {'name': 'Ben', 'age': 31, 'country': 'France', 'hobbies': ['coding', 'biking']},
    {'name': 'Quinn', 'age': 26, 'country': 'Ireland', 'hobbies': ['skiing']},
    {'name': 'Sasha', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Lebanon', 'hobbies': ['sports']},
    {'name': 'Alex', 'age': 28, 'country': 'Austria', 'hobbies': []}
]
```

How can I cound the items in 'hobbies' for an person, let's say Ben. I tried let(), sum(), and some If statements, but none work. Maybe I'm just wrong with the syntax or missing a step. Any help to point me in the right direction?

How would I be able to print the number of hobbies listed for example, for Ben 2, for Sasha 1, etc.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us your code?

Comment: Also not just the non-working code, but also the expected result, e.g. a dict mapping names to number of hobbies?

Comment: [Homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527), I take it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `len`, like so:

```
team = [
    {'name': 'Ben', 'age': 31, 'country': 'France', 'hobbies': ['coding', 'biking']},
    {'name': 'Quinn', 'age': 26, 'country': 'Ireland', 'hobbies': ['skiing']},
    {'name': 'Sasha', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Lebanon', 'hobbies': ['sports']},
    {'name': 'Alex', 'age': 28, 'country': 'Austria', 'hobbies': []}
]


for player in team:
    print('%s has %d hobbies' % (player['name'], len(player['hobbies'])))
```

Output:

```
Ben has 2 hobbies
Quinn has 1 hobbies
Sasha has 1 hobbies
Alex has 0 hobbies
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could try something like:

```
counts = {person["name"]:len(person.get("hobbies",[])) for person in team}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `.__len__()` for solution:

```
team = [
    {'name': 'Ben', 'age': 31, 'country': 'France', 'hobbies': ['coding', 'biking']},
    {'name': 'Quinn', 'age': 26, 'country': 'Ireland', 'hobbies': ['skiing']},
    {'name': 'Sasha', 'age': 24, 'country': 'Lebanon', 'hobbies': ['sports']},
    {'name': 'Alex', 'age': 28, 'country': 'Austria', 'hobbies': []}
]

for person in team:
    if person["hobbies"].__len__() > 1:
        print(person["name"],"has",str(person["hobbies"].__len__()),"hobbies")
    else:
        print(person["name"],"has",str(person["hobbies"].__len__()),"hobby")
```

output:

```
Ben has 2 hobbies
Quinn has 1 hobby
Sasha has 1 hobby
Alex has 0 hobby
```